# omp parallel for: Thread fails to assign value

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, openmp

I have a for loop parallelized by **OpenMP**. I want the parallel threads to fill an `std::vector<bool>` of `falses` with `trues`. Each thread should write to its own entry of the vector. But sometimes one assignment fails. How can this happen?

```
    int size = 10;
    std::vector<bool> vec(10);       // all entries contain false

#pragma omp parallel for
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
       vec[i] = true;                // sometimes this assignment fails for a thread
```

The vector may end up looking like this:
`true true true true false true true true true true`

Comment: Please upgrade your code to a [mcve] that includes the output and without obvious syntax errors (`#pragma comment`)

Comment: What output are you missing in my example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is due to how `std::vector<bool>` is stored. It is designed for space efficiency, and stores elements in individual bits, not bytes.  This means that assignments to `vec[0]`, `vec[1]`, ... `vec[7]` all write to the same byte in memory.  Since you have multiple threads writing to the same address (it will actually be a read-modify-write sequence), there is a race condition.  This can cause a write by one thread to be "undone" by a write of a later thread.

In addition, the potential performance benefit in a memory-intensive loop like this is not large due to the bandwidth limits of main memory.  Combined with the cache invalidation required by each thread, the threaded performance will likely be inferior to single threaded operation.

With the fundamental basic operation being done here (setting memory to true), just code it up as a standard non-OMP single thread loop.  The compiler will be able to optimize it to something reasonably performant.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This explains my problem. (The example was minized. In my actual code it is faster to keep the parallelization). I chose std::deque<bool> over std::vector<bool> in the end.

Answer (score 0):

As per the standard, all standard containers are required to avoid data races when the contents of the contained object in different elements in the same container are modified concurrently.
Except `std::vector<bool>`.
1201ProgramAlarm explains why.

`std::vector<bool>` is infamous for many issues - the most straight-forward solution is to use `std::vector<char>` instead. If you do that, your program is just fine, although you should not expect any performance boost from using OpenMP in that particular case.

Answer (score -1):

my openmp is rusty, but what comes to mind is `#pragma omp flush [(list)]`

> the flush directive in openmp may be used to identify a **synchronization** point, which is defined as a point in the execution of the program  where the executing thread needs to have a consistent view of memory.  A consistent view of memory has **2** requirements: all memory read/write operations **before** and **after** the flush directive must be performed either **before** or **after**.  this is often called a *memory fence*.   Page 163, parallel programming in openmp by Chandra,Dagum,Kohr,Maydan,McDonald,Menon; 2001

And there is much more detailed description on this in the book, as well as mention of variables not being retained in a buffer/register across any synchronization point, which per your posted code you are not doing.

with very little code posted, and I don't know how or when you are checking `vec[i]` so this would be my first guess... and then checking on the versions of the linux operating system, C compiler, and openmp versions involved...

but I don't expect an OS upgrade, a compiler upgrade, nor an openmp version upgrade, to correct what you are experiencing it's likely your code

much like what happens in standard C when doing `printf("hello")` without a following `fflush(stdout)` when you do **not** do `printf("hello\n")`.  The `\n` causes an inherent flush to happen on most all systems that is taken for granted.

Comment: After the for loop openMP should synchronize everything. The actual problem was the special definition of std::vector<bool>. Thanks for your reply though.